# Lower bound in function isn't actually the lower bound?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

In my college level Pre-Calculus class, my teacher discussed finding lower bounds of functions using Descartes' Rule of Signs, to see if the function has any variations in it.

Given $f(x) = x^3 - 10x^2 + 17x - 8$

We get that $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ = $\frac{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8}{\pm 1}$

If we use synthetic division, we can figure out that 2 is our lower bound, but a strange occurrence shows up if you try to use 1 as your divisor... It ends up returning a remainder of 0 as well.

My questions is: Why is the lower bound of the function $f(x)$ 2 if clearly 1 < 2, but 1 also works as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing [Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) with the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  Your expression for $\frac {p(x)}{q(x)}$ looks like the options for the rational roots of the polynomial, and in fact there is a double root at $1$ and a single root at $8$.  Decartes' rule of signs would look at the three changes of signs of the coefficients and say there are either one or three positive roots, which need not be rational.  It would also see no changes of sign when $x \lt 0$, so there are no negative roots.  Neither of these is involved in a lower bound of the function.  In fact, there is no lower bound.  The function becomes large and negative when $x$ is large and negative.

Comment: Going off of your last sentence, we learned that if the product after using the divisor (in this case 2) ends in a sequence such as $+ - + - $ or vice versa, it is considered a lower bound, yet I don't know of a proof that shows that IS a lower bound... Do you know why my teacher would give us this information if it's not always true? (She also says that she's run into issues where upper bounds are supposed to be all positive, and she's seen examples where they aren't ALL positive, but still have that value as an upper bound)

Comment: This is a strange use of "lower bound of a function".  Normally a lower bound for a function refers to some value $k$ such that $f(x) \ge k$ for all $x$  I also don't understand what you mean by the product after using the divisor.

Comment: Using synthetic division, she told us to look at the answer we get, and see if the results would form in a negative, positive, negative, etc. fashion where they alternate between positive and negative... I'm not quite sure why she thinks because of this, it must be a lower bound, but we have seen functions in the past that when following this guideline, that they ARE lower bounds. I'm curious as if there is a legitimate way to determine the lower bound from the synthetic division process.

Answer (score 0):

In synthetic division "lower bound" refers to a number below which there are no possible rational roots.  It is my understanding that the alternating positive and negative only indicates a lower bound when the divisor is negative (and the upper bound being indicated by all positives is only true when the divisor is positive.)